# How to exclude instances of the EC2 inventory in Ansible?

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible, ansible-inventory

We have an Ansible server using EC2 dynamic inventory:

- https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/contrib/inventory/ec2.py
- https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/contrib/inventory/ec2.ini

However, with the number of instances we have, running `./ec2.py --list` or `./ec2.py --refresh-cache` returns a 28,000 line JSON response.

This I assume, causes it to randomly fail (returns a Python stack trace) as it only receives a partial response when sending a call to AWS, but is then fine if ran again.

Which is why I want to know if there's a way to cut this down.

I know there is a way to include specific instances by tag in the ec2.ini (i.e. `# instance_filters = tag:env=staging`), but with
the way our instances are tagged, is there a way to exclude
instances instead (something that would look similar to: `# instance_filters = tag:name=!dev`)?

Comment: _This I assume, causes it to randomly fail (returns a Python stack trace)_ have you opened an issue with ansible showing that stack trace? Because you may be solving the wrong problem -- I can appreciate that a huge JSON blob is ugly to look at, but for a computer it shouldn't be a problem, especially if the `cache_max_age` is a reasonable value

Comment: I second the comment from @MatthewLDaniel if the inventory randomly fails this is not an expected behavior so report it to Ansible github repository.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a way to exclude instances instead

Just for completeness, I wanted to point out that the "inventory protocol" for ansible is super straightforward to implement, and they even have a [JSON Schema](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.6.3/examples/inventory_script_schema.json#L1) for it.

You can see an example of the output it is expecting by running the newly included [`ansible-inventory`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/v2.6.3/bin/ansible-inventory) script with `--list` to see the output it generates from one of the `.ini` style inventories, and then use that to emit your own:

```
$ printf 'somehost ansible_user=bob\n\n[some_group]\nsomehost\n' > sample
$ ansible-inventory -i ./sample --list
```

What I am suggesting is that you might have better luck making a custom inventory script, that *does* know your local business practices, rather than trying to force `ec2.py` into running a negation query (which, as best I can tell, it will not do).

To generate dynamic inventory, just make an executable -- as far as I know it can be in any language at all -- and then point the `-i` at the executable script instead of a "normal" file. Ansible will invoke that program, and operate on the JSON output as the inventory. There are [several examples](https://gist.github.com/search?l=Python&p=2&q=ansible+inventory) people have posted as gists, in all kinds of languages.

I would still love it if you would file an issue with ansible about `ec2.py`, because you have the situation that can make the bug report concrete for them in ways that a simple "it doesn't work for large inventories" doesn't capture. But in the mean time, writing your own inventory provider is actually less work than it sounds.

Answer (score 0):

I use the option *pattern_exclude* in ec2.ini:

```
# If you want to exclude any hosts that match a certain regular expression
pattern_exclude = staging-*
```

and

```
hostname_variable = tag_Name
```